# How to strptime a time string as a different from local time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, strptime

When I use `Time.strptime` in my local computer, I got like this:

```
ENV['LC_CTYPE']
=>"ja_JP.UTF-8"
Time.strptime("10/12/2015-4:05pm", '%m/%d/%Y-%I:%M%p')
=> 2015-10-12 16:05:00 +0900
```

How can I parse the string as a different time zone like `'Central Time (US & Canada)'`?

I tried with `Time.zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`, but the result was same.

I want to use the function in Rails environment so it's ok to use `active_support`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%Z` is how you represent timezone in date/time format.  Try the following:

```
time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
DateTime.strptime "10/12/2015-4:05pm #{time_zone}", '%m/%d/%Y-%I:%M%p %Z'
```